createEntityAdapter add an item on the top on the list instead of the bottom
I want to add an item top of the list instead of the bottom.
.addCase(createPost.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
   postEntityAdaptor.addOne(state, action.payload);
})

I have a list of posts when the user creates a new post so it should be added to the top of the array. but when I am using postEntityAdaptor.addOne so it adds an item at the bottom of the list.

It's not really clear what you mean by "on the top" or "the bottom" here. Does it really matter what order your data is stored in? You can compute a derived sorted order when selecting the state. Would adding a sort comparator to the entity definition help? If not can you [edit] to provide more complete details and [mcve] of the relevant code?

I have a list of posts when user create new post so it's should be add to the top of the array. but when I used postEntityAdaptor.addOne so it's adding item at the bottom on the list.

I have fixed this issue by adding the sortComparer
const postEntityAdaptor = createEntityAdapter({
   sortComparer: (a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt,
});

